# Trying to traverse (walk) the directory of an esp32 using Micropython

Tags: esp32, micropython

````
```
# try.py
import uos
dir = 16384

def walk(t): # recursive function
    print('-',t)
    w = uos.ilistdir(t)
    for x in w:
        L = list(x)
        print(L[0], L[1], L[3])
        if L[1] == dir:
            walk(L[0])
        else:
            return
    

z = uos.ilistdir()
for x in z:
    L = list(x)
    print(L[0], L[1], L[3])
    if L[1] == dir:
        walk(L[0])

```
````

The code stops with an error on line 7, with an error:

**Output:**

Traverse.py 32768 773

boot.py 32768 139

lib 16384 0

-lib

one 16384 0

-one

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "stdin", line 21, in

File "stdi>", line 12, in walk

File "<tdin", line 7, in walk

OSError: [Errno 2] ENOENT

**The directory structure is:**

lib

```
one

    two

        three

    three.py
```

boot.py

main.py

one.py

Traverse.py

**It seems that it stops on a directory that has no files in it**

Comment: So what is the question? You don't know to handle the exception with `try...catch` or something else?

Comment: Why do I get an Error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have an ESP to test, but there are some problems here:

- you shouldn't return if the entry is a file but instead continue, this is why it stops too soon
- you should skip the current and parent directory to avoid infinite recursion
- when recursing you have to prepend the top directory, that is probably the reason for the error i.e. your code calls `walk('two')` but there is no such directory, it has to be `one/two`)
- you can use the walk function on the current directory so that last bit where you duplicate the implementation isn't needed.

Additionally:

- iterating `ilistdir` returns `tuple`s which can be indexed as well so no need to convert it into a `list`
- and passing collections to `print` directly also works, no need for separate `print(x[0], x[1], ...`)

Adpatation, with slightly different printing of full paths so it's easier to follow:

```
import uos

dir_code = 16384

def walk(t):
    print('-', t)
    for x in uos.ilistdir(t):
        print(x)
        if x[1] == dir_code and x[0] != '.' and x[0] != '..':
            walk(t + '/' + x[0])
    
walk('.')
```

This will still print directories twice, add all that indexing makes things hard to read. Adaptation with tuple unpacking and printing directories once:

```
import uos

dir_code = 16384

def walk(top):
    print(top)
    for name, code, _ in uos.ilistdir(top):
        if code != dir_code:
            print(top + '/' + name)
        elif name not in ('.', '..'):
            walk(top + '/' + name)
    
walk('.')
```

Comment: The first code worked fine, but (as you said) it printed the Directories twice.
the second came up with an error:
    File "<stdin>", line 7, in walk
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
But I especially thank you for your corrections and explanation of the errors and simplifications of my code. Although I have been professionally coding for the past 60 years, I am not an experienced Python coder.

Comment: @user1530405 perhaps the tuple returned by ilistdir has 4 values, in which case you'd use something like `for name, code, _, __ in uos.ilistdir(top):` instead

Comment: Yes, that is the answer. Thank you